# Restrict input totally on an input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, forms, input

Form fields can have restrictions applied to them to stop input of numbers, characters or symbols but out of interest is there a way to completely restrict input of any kind. For example.

**Javascript**

```
    var digitsOnly = /[1234567890]/g;
    var integerOnly = /[0-9\.]/g;
    var alphaOnly = /[A-Za-z]/g;

    function restrictCharacters(myfield, e, restrictionType) {
        if (!e) var e = window.event
        if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
        else if (e.which) code = e.which;
        var character = String.fromCharCode(code);
        if (code==27) { this.blur(); return false; }
        if (!e.ctrlKey && code!=9 && code!=8 && code!=36 && code!=37 && code!=38 && (code!=39 || (code==39 && character=="'")) && code!=40) {
            if (character.match(restrictionType)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        }
```

**HTML:**

```
<form action="" method="get">
<p><label for="input1">digitsOnly: </label> <input type="text" id="input1" onkeypress="return restrictCharacters(this, event, digitsOnly);" /></p>

<p><label for="input2">integerOnly</label> <input type="text" id="input2" onkeypress="return restrictCharacters(this, event, integerOnly);" /></p>

<p><label for="input3">alphaOnly</label> <input type="text" id="input3" onkeypress="return restrictCharacters(this, event, alphaOnly);" /></p>
```

To stop total restriction would I presume you would conjoin the different regex vars, but how would you prevent users copying and pasting or dragging content into the field as well as prevent key-press operations?

Answer (score 2):

You can give it the "readonly" attribute:

```
<input type=text readonly=readonly ...>
```

The "readonly" attribute is distinct from the "disabled" attribute; a form field can be "readonly" but it will still be posted with the form or serialized by jQuery. The "disabled" attribute, when present, makes it as if the field wasn't even there once the form is posted to the server.

You can style your readonly fields with CSS:

```
input[readonly] { border-width: 0px; border-style: none; }
```

(or whatever).  You can set the property from JavaScript too:

```
document.getElementById("someInput").readOnly = true;
```

Comment: Thats a lot easier than using JS, I did not know that existed

Answer (score 0):

You can also completely disable it:

```
<input type="text" disabled=true >
```

Comment: Yes, but then it won't be posted with the form. That *may* be OK, of course.

Comment: The main thing about disabled inputs that I really like is that the browser clearly shows you can't edit it (it's grayed out and doesn't show a caret if you click on the text). To get around the element not being posted with the form, I typically add a hidden element with the same value and the right name.